# Mobile app framework for mobile and AngularJS for desktop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

Background: I've recently learned Ruby on Rails and have just learned to use JavaScript as well as JQuery. I've created some web apps using both.

Goal: To create a small e-commerce-like site using Rails backend but optimize for mobile. There will be a shopping cart but no built-in payment system.

I've seen these mobile app frameworks like ionic for mobile but am aware that ionic doesn't play nice with internet explorer for the desktop folks.

My idea is to use a mobile app framework like ionic or such for mobile and using a web framework like AngularJS for the desktop users for the same site. Or use a mobile app framework for mobile and no web framework for desktop?

I'm currently not advanced enough in my development skills to create adapters to use ionic or other mobile app frameworks to work friendly with desktop browsers. I'm looking for the more developer convenient route with style and with less configuration.

Please advise your recommendations and if you think that this setup can be done with minimal configuration with Rails as the backend.

Comment: This might give you some ideas.  Ionic is great for mobile.  But check out Electron for desktop. https://medium.com/@kaumac/cross-platform-apps-using-ionic-electron-angularjs-and-firebase-with-shared-codebase-chapter-1-52859cc6d742

Comment: @dustmouse Thank you! That did give me ideas :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hybrid solutions will always be less good than native, in terms of performance, size and stability.

But Hybrid solutions are improving with time and ionic is a great solution, it avoids you to develop specific app for each platform. 
To develop your hybrid app i warmly recommand you to use AngularJS, to me jQuery is not made to develop big application.